# ERR! When i npm install --global@angular/@letest in project justdo

Tags: angularjs, npm, sass, npm-install, npm-scripts

When i npm install --global@angular/@letest so this ERR! coming please help
[image: i]

Comment: looks like you have not installed the right python version, which is required by one of the npm module.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong command I suppose
Try using the following command

```
npm i -g @angular/@latest
```